# Alternative to use since negative padding doesn't exist

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have a navigation pane on the left side of the viewport:

[image]

I wish to make the pink and brown `li` elements smaller, however the only alternative I see is to use something like "negative padding" (which I clearly know it doesn't exist).

Here's my code:

```
<div ng-controller="navbarAndFooterController" class="ng-hide" ng-hide="adminNavBool">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hide" data-activates="side-nav" data-sidenav="left" data-menuwidth="330" data-closeonclick="false">Hide menu</a>
        <ul id="side-nav" class="side-nav fixed">
            <li class="nav-title white center-align">
                <button type="button" ng-click="go('/admin/admin_hub')" class="btn-floating brown darken-2 waves-effect waves-light" tooltipped data-tooltip="Panel de Control - Inicio"><i class="material-icons">home</i></button>
                <button type="button" ng-click="go('/admin_login')" class="btn-floating red darken-2 waves-effect waves-light" tooltipped data-tooltip="Cerrar Sesión - Ir a página principal"><i class="material-icons">power_settings_new</i></button>
            </li>
            <li class="white-text pink darken-2 center-align nav-title">Categorías</li>
            <li><a href="#/admin/actualizar_categoria">Actualizar Categoría</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/admin/nueva_categoria">Nueva Categoría</a></li>
            <li class="white-text pink darken-2 center-align nav-title">Galerías</li>
            <li class="white-text brown darken-2 center-align nav-subtitle">Subcategorías</li>
            <li><a href="#/admin/actualizar_subcategoria">Actualizar Subcategoría</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/admin/nueva_subcategoria">Nueva Subcategoría</a></li>
            <li class="white-text brown darken-2 center-align nav-subtitle">Fotos de Galería</li>
            <li><a href="#/admin/actualizar_foto">Actualizar Foto</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/admin/nueva_foto">Nueva Foto</a></li>
            <li class="white-text pink darken-2 center-align nav-title">Misceláneo</li>
            <li class="white-text brown darken-2 center-align nav-subtitle">Configuración de Usuario</li>
            <li><a href="#/admin/cambiar_contrasena">Cambiar contraseña</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/admin/cambiar_correo">Cambiar correo</a></li>
            <li class="white-text brown darken-2 center-align nav-subtitle">Páginas Editables</li>
            <li><a href="#/admin/actualizar_pagina_de_inicio">Página de Inicio</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Relevant custom CSS:

```
.nav-title{
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.nav-subtitle{
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

(Using materialize as my front-end framework). Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: did you try using **line-height**? and do share a fiddle

Comment: line-height did the trick. Please post this as answer so I can mark it.

Comment: The css you provided is not relevant at all. You need to provide us the css for  li and a tags not the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `line-height` `css` rule you do not need negative `padding`, it will help.

```
.li{
   line-height: 20px;//or something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to adjust the height property of the list elements. By this, all the list elements are of the same height.

```
.nav-title{
    height : 20px;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.nav-subtitle{
    height : 20px;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is in other styling classes:

```
.white-text? .pink? darken-2? center-align?
```

[This basic JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epdoh3ua/) look fine

Comment: Those classes are only to center text, and colors (white for text and pink darken-2 for the pink color of the li element. Line height was the css property that solved my problem